# python - please help cant figure out how to add up user input of an array

Tags: python, arrays, range

how do I Write using python a function, sum(a), that takes an array, a, of numbers and returns their sum?

I tried this but i am unable to figure out how get the user input of the array of number this is what i have so far

Comment: You seem to be missing some code in your question. If you have trouble formatting it, see [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)

Comment: This smells like homework.  Please post your work so far as Martijn has requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You take the built-in function [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>> sum(range(10))
45
```

From the documentation:

> Sums `start` and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. `start` defaults to `0`. The iterable‘s items are normally numbers, and the `start` value is not allowed to be a string.

If the user input is in the form of strings, you need to turn those into integers first. A generator expression could do that for you:

```
>>> user_input = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
>>> sum(int(v) for v in user_input)
45
```

Comment: For the user input part (the bit it seems like the OP is having a problem with) you can use `input()` (or `raw_input()` in py3k).